# Usage of world keel in conversation

Tags: word-usage

Can I use "keel" in sentence,

**You should keel yourself.**

Meaning I want to convey is that person should calm himself down.
Is it valid usage?

Comment: Have you tried looking up 'keel' in a dictionary? As far as I know there is no definition with this sense.

Comment: @KateBunting Try the on-line OED - if your local library has a subscription you can use it free-of-charge from home. Once you have used the real thing, all other dictionaries pale into - well perhaps not "insignificance" - but you get my meaning.

Comment: We do occasionally say "keep yourself [on an even keel](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+an+even+keel)" where the **keel** refers to the lowest structural part of a ship, but I have never heard "keel yourself."

Comment: @WeatherVane No it has disappeared from modern use - but it does seem it was alive and well in 1883.

Comment: @WS2 As a retired librarian, I'm well aware of the existence of the OED. However, the existence of an archaic definition doesn't mean that the OP can use it as suggested.

Comment: @KateBunting  My apologies Kate. I remember you had already explained to me you were a retired librarian.

Comment: @WeatherVane That *keel* doesn't seem to be relevant here.

Comment: @ws Kate has a point. You don't dig through archives to check if a word and its usage are valid in contemporary English. Dictionaries primarily focus on language as is current.

Comment: @Kris, my comment was relevant to the extent that it is a current use of the word **keel** and in a similar context, as one is calm when on an "even keel", for the interest of OP.

Comment: an '*even keel*' is more about being balanced than necessarily calming down. [with reference to holding a person or thing steady, or to restoring stability or normality after a difficult period](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/68156786?redirectedFrom=even+keel#eid). '*Cool yourself*' though, seems to fit fairly well in my mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb ***keel***, from the Germanic *kölen* (modern form *kühlen*) simply means "to cool".

(There are other verb senses to do with ploughing, and/or conveying in a keel. But they do not seem relevant here.)

An OED entry from 1883 illustrates its use in exactly the way you propose:

***1883   T. Lees Easther's Gloss. Dial. Almondbury & Huddersfield (at cited word)   A person may keel himself, or let his tea keel.***

**But beware, there are no more recent examples, and it is not a form I have ever heard used, except in Shakespeare's *Loves Labours Lost*.** The latter (see below) refers to the practice of "keeling the pot" i.e. pouring cold water into a hot vessel on the fire to prevent it boiling over.

> From “Love’s Labor ’s Lost,” Act V. Sc. 2. by William Shakespeare.
>
> WHEN icicles hang by the wall,
>
> And Dick the shepherd blows his> nail,
>
> And Tom bears logs into the hall,
>
> And milk comes frozen home in pail,
>
> When blood is nipped, and ways be foul,
>
> Then> nightly sings the staring owl,
>
> To-whoo; To-whit, to-whoo, a merry note,
>
> **While greasy Joan doth keel the pot.**

Comment: To answer the OP's Q more directly, you may want to add "No. It's **not** a valid usage today."

Comment: @Kris Not "valid"? That suggests there is a law against it.

Comment: An answer need to be categorical, supported by a reference to canonical source so it could be useful to  the asker, right? You could very well say "valid" and **support** it.

Comment: @Kris But I have pointed out in my answer that there are no recent examples, and that I had never heard it used. Is that not sufficient to convey the fact that the word has gone out of fashion? As for "valid" and "invalid" they are terms I might apply to something like a driving licence. "Is my UK licence valid in Japan?" or "Is your passport valid, or has it gone out of date?" "Is the medication you are using valid or invalid as regards banned substances in sport".